# Problems installing npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I do have a lot of problems with phonegap.
I have installed node.js last year (node-0.10.5)
But how do I install npm? When I type in "brew install npm" I get this:
my-mbp:~ me$ brew install npm
Warning: node-0.10.5 already installed

how do I install and get npm to run?

Comment: did you try using the installer on nodejs.org ? I believe that it should update your version of node and install NPM.

Comment: Thanks for answering,I downloaded and installed that now but don't know how to enable it in the Terminal

Comment: If you used `brew install node` to install Node.js, it includes `npm` by default. You have to use [an opt-out option](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/f047d1fc3368ff22524177e60c428e671dc1aa3e/Library/Formula/node.rb#L23) to exclude it. And, the `npm` formula is just [an alias of `node`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/f047d1fc3368ff22524177e60c428e671dc1aa3e/Library/Aliases/npm).

Comment: Ok when I type in npm -v I'm getting 1.4.28 - I guess thats the latest version?

Comment: @DanielvonMatterhorn That's the latest 1.x version. You may be able to update to 2.x using npm itself -- `npm update -g npm`.

Comment: I did typ in "npm update -g npm" but when I check with "npm -v" I get this: "-bash: npm: command not found" It doesn't even give me the state of my latest version any more